# How can I restrict the amount of time a PHP include will wait for a result?

Tags: php, include, timeout

I'm including a local class that requests a file from a remote server. This process is rather unreliable — because the remote server is often overloaded — and I sometimes have to wait 20 or so seconds before the include gives up and continues.

I would like to have a limit on the execution time of the included script; say, five seconds.

Current code:

```
include('siteclass.class.php');
```

**Update:**

My code inside the class:

```
$movie = str_replace(" ","+",$movie);
$string = join('',file($siteurl.$l.'/moviename-'.$movie));

if(!$i) { static $i = 1;}
if($file_array = $string)
{
    $result = Return_Substrings($file_array, '<item>', '</item>');

    foreach($result as $res) {
```

That's basically it, as far as the loading goes. The internal processing takes about 0.1 s. I guess that's pretty doable.

Comment: Its strange if you have a script which can sometimes do without an external class. I mean either use it always or never. 20 seconds is way too slow. I think you should rethink your software.

Comment: What code actually performs the request?  If you use cURL for example, you can set a timeout, and handle the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that I didn't test this code, take this like a proposition :

```
$fp = fopen('siteclass.class.php', 'r');

stream_set_timeout($fp, 2);
stream_set_timeout($fp,$timeout);
$info = stream_get_meta_data($fp);

if ($info['timed_out']) {
  echo "Connection Timed Out!";
} else {
  $file = '';
  while (!feof($fp)) {
    $file .= fgets($fp);
  }
  eval($file);
}
```

The timeout is set in seconds, so the example set it to two seconds.

Comment: thx for the help. it turns out that my php file returns blank. No errors nothing, just blank. I guess it has something to do that i'm not including the class inside the page. (not sure though>not an expert), but i'm missing some variables requested in the class. (some global variables set, such as '$movie'. What do you think? Thx anyway!

Comment: ok, i apologize for my incompetence.. But, it turned out i forgot to strip the '<?php' from the class files.

anyway, it works now! thx!!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an exact fit to what you're looking for, but this will set the time limit for the include and execution to a total of 25 seconds. If the time limit is reached, it throws a fatal error.

```
set_time_limit(25);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `set_time_limit()` might do what you want:

[PHP Manual for that function](http://us.php.net/set_time_limit)

Answer (score 0):

Fix the included code to have a timeout on the HTTP Request and then recover nicely, instead of just aborting by setting a time limit on the script itself.

My advice would be to get to the root of the problem instead of looking for a workaround.

Comment: what do you recommend with my (newly updated) code? i do agree with your vision > fix it at the root. thx